# Specify font in matplotlib

Tags: linux, python-3.x, matplotlib, fonts

I'm trying to specify a font to use in my plotting in matplotlib.  I've moved my *.ttf files to a new directory here: */usr/share/fonts/truetype/avenir*

I have two problems.  Firstly, I can't get matplotlib to find my nice new fonts!

```
Avenir45 = {'family': 'avenir',
            'weight': 'normal',
            'size': 14}
matplotlib.rc('font', **Avenir45)
```

which results in

```
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1288: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['avenir'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
```

Which leads on to my second problem, that when I look up the font families:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager
flist = matplotlib.font_manager.get_fontconfig_fonts()
families = [matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(fname=fname).get_family() for fname in flist]
```

I get a huge list which is populated with nothing but 'avenir'!

Any ideas?

Comment: Does "nothing but 'avenir'" mean that the huge list contains a single item, namely 'avenir'?

Comment: No, that it returns "avenir" for the family of every font

Comment: I see. Probably you want to use `.get_name()` instead of `.get_family()`.

Comment: Can you help me with the syntax of forcing a specific font to be used in matplotlib please?

Comment: I guess there are enough questions on this already, right? (1) Put the font into the font directory (2) possibly delete font cache (3) find out name of font (4) use it.

Comment: You'd think that, but I've been at this for over an hour now without a great deal of success.  All I want to do it set the default font in matplotlib from a *.ttf file.  Do you know a quick way of doing this?

Comment: Never mind, think I've got it. Thanks